# breaking road segments based on another shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, road, grids-graticules, atlas

I am using QGIS 2.18 and have a road celterline and a grid shapefile which I am using to create an atlas book.  What I want to do is break each road at the edge of each grid that it crosses but I have been unable to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your grid is polygons. Then you can use Intersection tool.

Found in:

Vector> Geoprocessing Tools> Intersection

If your gird is lines. You can use the "Split lines with lines" tool, from the Geoprocessing Toolbox.

Comment: For some reason when I tried the "Vector> Geoprocessing Tools> Intersection" it clipped the roads however the Split lines with lines tool worked perfectly!